# Best way to apply "one-shot quick fixes" to computers and users?

Tags: windows, user-management, desktop

We often suffer from situations where we need to apply a quick fix for a bunch of users/computers.

A quick fix can be a copy job, deleting a users browser cache or adding registry keys to HKCU to a group of users, etc. etc. Most of the time this fixes become necessary because of our confusing environment or bad change-testing habits.

Till to date we have been using group policies (preferences), SCCM packets and scripts which are getting called by our chaotic login script. I never got rid of the fealing that we are misusing this products.

Can you recommend any management product that is designed to roll out such one-shot-quick-fixes in a controlled maner? How do you handle such tasks?

Comment: In general, this is not the place for "product, service, or learning material recommendations". See: http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic  If your question is not closed as off-topic, I would say that it might also too vague as there is no specific situation at hand. There are so many different actions that could be considered "quick fixes" that I can't see any one tool covering even a majority of situations.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you are doing it wrong?  AD GPO is perfect for maintaining machine configuration even when you have machines exempted from specific policies.  SCCM is the right way to distribute software and can be used to maintain config as well.  Using the login script for one-time fixes might work, but you do need to clean up (out of sight is out of mind).

These are all good tools to have access to. You have different problems and different tools for addressing them.